# why when I call a function passing a reference to an array, the array is changing in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, function

I was following a tutorial on creating a little game in Ruby when I fell into a bug I couldn't understand. When I looked closely, I realized that the error was happening in line 51 of the `fogefoge.rb` on the call of `nova_posicao = calcula_nova_posicao heroi, direcao`.
At this point of the tutorial, the  heroe "H" should be able to move around with the keys "ASDW". I noticed that the array `heroi` at line 49 `heroi = encontra_jogador mapa` has been changed and that was introducing the bug in the application. After that I created another variable called `heroi2` and the code worked.
Why when I call line 51 of `fogefoge.rb`, the array is changing?
From what I've been reading in Rubydocs, I just can't understand why this is happening.

```
File "main.rb"
require_relative "fogefoge"

inicia_fogefoge
```

```
File "mapa1.txt"
XXXXX
X H X
X X X
X X X
X   X
  X  
 XXX 
  X  
X F X
XXXXX
```

```
File "ui.rb"
def da_boas_vindas
  puts "bem vindo ao Foge-foge"
  puts "Qual é o seu nome?"
  nome = gets.strip
  puts "\n\n\n\n\n"
  puts "Começaremos o jogo para você, #{nome}"
  nome
end
def desenha(mapa)
  puts mapa
end
def pede_movimento
  puts "Para onde deseja ir?"
  movimento = gets.strip
end
```

```
#File "fogefoge.rb"
require_relative "ui"


def le_mapa(numero)
  arquivo = "mapa#{numero}.txt"
  texto = File.read(arquivo)
  mapa = texto.split "\n"
#  p mapa
end
def encontra_jogador(mapa)
  caractere_do_heroi = "H"
  mapa.each_with_index do |linha_atual, linha|
    coluna_do_heroi   = linha_atual.index caractere_do_heroi
    if coluna_do_heroi
      return [linha, coluna_do_heroi]
    end
  end
end
def calcula_nova_posicao(heroi, direcao)
  case direcao
    when "W"
      heroi[0] -= 1
    when "S"
      heroi[0] += 1
    when "A"
      heroi[1] -= 1
    when "D"
      heroi[1] += 1
  end
  heroi
end
def posicao_valida?(mapa, posicao)
  linhas = mapa.size
  colunas = mapa[0].size
  estourou_linhas = posicao[0] < 0 || posicao[0] >= linhas
  estourou_colunas = posicao[1] < 0 || posicao[1] >= colunas
  if estourou_linhas || estourou_colunas
    return false
  end
  if mapa[posicao[0]][posicao[1]] == "X"
    return false
  end
  true
end
def joga(nome)
  mapa = le_mapa 1
  while true
    desenha mapa
    direcao = pede_movimento
    heroi = encontra_jogador mapa
    #heroi2 = encontra_jogador mapa
    nova_posicao = calcula_nova_posicao heroi, direcao #At this call

    if !posicao_valida? mapa, nova_posicao
      next
    end
    mapa[heroi[0]][heroi[1]] = " "
    mapa[nova_posicao[0]][nova_posicao[1]] = "H"
  end
end

def inicia_fogefoge
  nome = da_boas_vindas
  joga nome
end
```

I was expecting that the "H" would move around through the blank spaces, but the "H" was repeated to a few directions

OUTPUT:

```
bem vindo ao Foge-foge
Qual é o seu nome?
marcos





Começaremos o jogo para você, marcos
XXXXX
X H X
X X X
X X X
X   X
  X  
 XXX 
  X  
X F X
XXXXX
Para onde deseja ir?
d
XXXXX
X H X
X X X
X X X
X   X
  X  
 XXX 
  X  
X F X
XXXXX
Para onde deseja ir?
D
XXXXX
X HHX
X X X
X X X
X   X
  X  
 XXX 
  X  
X F X
XXXXX
Para onde deseja ir?
S
XXXXX
X HHX
X X X
X X X
X   X
  X  
 XXX 
  X  
X F X
```

if you uncomment the second reference at line 50 and then change line 51 to `nova_posicao = calcula_nova_posicao heroi2, direcao` then the code work.

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: This is the whole point of references: If you have a reference to an object, you can apply modifying methods to this object. If you don't want this to occur, either pass a copy of the object, or turn to a functional programming language (for instance Haskell).

Comment: Hi! We can't tell which line is line 51 from this, because we don't get line numbers. Can you edit this to indicate which line you're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `calcula_nova_posicao` implementation alters the passed `heroi` array and then returns it. Therefore, your `nova_posicao` and `heroi` will be the same after the call (not only containing the same values, but both referring to the very same object).

Here's a quick example on how to verify this: ([`equal?`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-equal-3F) checks if two objects are in fact the same object)

```
a = [0, 0]
b = calcula_nova_posicao(a, "S")

a #=> [1, 0]  <- note that "a" has changed!
b #=> [1, 0]

a.equal?(b) #=> true
```

> why when I call a function passing a reference to an array, the array is changing in ruby?

This is a very fundamental behavior in Ruby. Some objects are *mutable*, i.e. you can alter such objects by sending certain messages to them (so-called *destructive methods*). Examples of mutable objects are strings, hashes and arrays. It doesn't matter how or where the (destructive) message is sent or who sends it. Once received, the object will alter itself.

Here's an example of two variables `a` and `b` referring to the same object, a string. If you send the [`upcase!`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-upcase-21) message to the string, it will upcase its characters and both variables will reflect that change: (because they are still referring to the same object which now has changed)

```
a = "foo"
b = a

a.upcase!   # or b.upcase!

a #=> "FOO"
b #=> "FOO"
```

The same applies to method arguments. If you pass a mutable object into a method, the method can alter it, just like you can outside the method:

```
def my_method(s)
  s.upcase!
end

a = "foo"
my_method(a)

a #=> "FOO"
```

---

Back to your problem. You probably want `calcula_nova_posicao` to 1) return a *new* array and 2) leave the passed-in array unchanged. The latter is important to clear the current `H` from the map. But it's also a good idea in general to not change arguments within methods because it can lead to unexpected results and hard to find bugs.

Here's one implementation:

```
def calcula_nova_posicao(heroi, direcao)
  case direcao
  when "W"
    [heroi[0] - 1, heroi[1]]
  when "S"
    [heroi[0] + 1, heroi[1]]
  when "A"
    [heroi[0], heroi[1] - 1]
  when "D"
    [heroi[0], heroi[1] + 1]
  end
end
```

Here's another one using [array decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition):

```
def calcula_nova_posicao(heroi, direcao)
  y, x = heroi
  case direcao
  when "W" then y -= 1
  when "S" then y += 1
  when "A" then x -= 1
  when "D" then x += 1
  end
  [y, x]
end
```

You might consider writing *tests* for your methods.